# iPhone : Problem regarding Hidden TabBar Controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uitabbarcontroller

In my app Tabbar is Hidden,

But trying that it display the screen as seen below.

[image]

I am using following code to hide tabbar

```
 [self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar setHidden:YES];
```

How can I display any image on that place or can cover that place with my view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add any UIView/UIImageView to the current screen you are showing in your question. Make sure your view's frame is 416. I want you to make the screenshot's viewController height is 416. This way it will shown complete. Try it or if still it doesn't help send me demo code by mail I'll solve your problem.

**UPDATE**

try this code to hide tabbar before pushing the view on stack use

```
UIViewController *vController = alloc initwithnib// just for example your actual code will be here
[vController hidesBottomBarWhenPushed];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vController animated:YES];
```

Comment: hey I am trying to set UIViews height but still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "hidden" property for the UITabBarController, I would probably animate it off the screen (as in having frame.location.y one pixel greater than the height of your view).

You can use UIView animations to get a nice effect for this, and at the same time you can animate your view to fill the entire screen.

Answer (score -1):

ok, I have this when i remove my tab bar controller for a particular screen.

You need to set the background color / background image of the app's UIWindow.I did mine quite noobishly in interface builder but somebody will share the correct code to do so.

let me know how you get on,

Comment: what if his view's background color is white and he set black color on window?

Comment: if the views background color is white, then just set background color of window to white. seriously! think!

Comment: further more, if all the views have the same background - my answer would be the perfect solution. there was no need to down vote a perfectly valid answer!